# Qual é a diferença entre __CLASS__ e get_called_class?

Tags: php, classes

No PHP, conheço dois métodos de exibir o nome da classe atual que está sendo chamada: através da constante mágica `__CLASS__` e da função `get_called_class()`.

Aparentemente, as duas fazem a mesma coisa.

```
class A 
{
     public static function className()
     { 
          echo get_called_class();
     }  
}


class B
{
     public static function className()
     { 
          echo __CLASS__;
     }  
}


B::className(); // 'B'
A::className(); // 'A'
```

Existe diferença de performance entre elas?

Existe alguma diferença na hora de chamá-las?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazendo os testes após ver esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594111/1518921), elas tem efeitos diferentes em situações quando estendemos uma classe:

- `get_called_class` retorna o nome da classe atual e não da onde foi declarado:

  ```
  <?php
  class Foo
  {
      static public function digaMeuNome()
      {
          var_dump(get_called_class());
      }
  }

  class Bar extends Foo
  {
  }

  Foo::digaMeuNome(); // Retorna Foo
  Bar::digaMeuNome(); // Retorna Bar
  ```
- `__CLASS__` retorna o nome da classe aonde o método foi declarado, ou seja o método `digaMeuNome` foi declarado em `Foo`:

  ```
  <?php
  class Foo
  {
      static public function digaMeuNome()
      {
          var_dump(__CLASS__);
      }
  }

  class Bar extends Foo
  {
  }

  Foo::digaMeuNome(); // Retorna Foo
  Bar::digaMeuNome(); // Retorna Foo
  ```

Comment: A resposta ficou um pouco simples, mas vou tentar complementar mais a tarde.

Comment: Mas era isso mesmo que eu estava esperando :)